# mysql_num_rows returns null every time

Tags: php

```
if (isset($_GET["val"])) {
    $val = $_GET["val"];
    $sql1 = "select count(*) as count from staff_log l where l.time_in is null and l.time_out is not null and l.date_today = curdate() and l.staff_id = ".$val.";";

    $result1 = mysql_num_rows($sql1);
}
```

Comment: Avoid using `mysql_*` extensions. For this, where is `mysql_query`?

Comment: make `query` first than `mysql_num_rows`.

Comment: are you using `mysql_query()`

Answer (score 2):

add this line...

```
$result = mysql_query( $sql1);
$result1 = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

you must define query in `mysql_query()` function;

Comment: Do the solution with `mysqli_*` And add some warning message for not using `mysql_*`....

Comment: yeap... mysql_* is deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_num_rows()` returns, as shown in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php):

> The number of rows in a result set on success or FALSE on failure.

This means that there was an error executing it, which is apparently because you didn't run any query (`mysql_query()`).

Note that the php manual also has the following warning at the top of the page:

> This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Answer (score 0):

first execute the query and then  num_rows

> The original MySQL extension is now deprecated, and will generate E_DEPRECATED errors when connecting to a database. Instead, use the MYSQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions.

try this

```
if (isset($_GET["val"]))
{
$val = $_GET["val"];
$sql1 = "select count(*) as count from staff_log l where l.time_in is null and l.time_out is not null and l.date_today = curdate() and l.staff_id = ".$val.";";

$result = mysql_query($sql1);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost right, please view the below code. You need to use **mysql_query()**, The **mysql_query()** is used to execute query of the default database.

```
if (isset($_GET["val"])) 
{
    $val = $_GET["val"];
    $sql1 = "select count(*) as count from staff_log l where l.time_in is null and l.time_out is not null and l.date_today = curdate() and l.staff_id ='$val'";
    $sql2 = mysql_query($sql1); // Execute the query first 
    $result1 = mysql_num_rows($sql2); // Get the number of rows from executed query result.
    echo "The count is $result1";
}
```